# Split line to hash keys

Tags: perl, hash, split, line

I have a line like this
`3:0 6:0 12:0 13:0 17:0 17:11 25:0 26:0 31:0 32:70 33:70 51:70 52:70 84:0 84:2 108:0 127:0 131:0 132:0 133:0 159:0 206:28 250:0`

I want to split the line and make a hash with empty keys, the final hash should be like this

```
%hash = ( 
  "3:0" => '',
  "6:0" => '',
  ...
)
```

I've done it by this way

```
my @tmp = split(/\s/, $line);
for (@tmp){
  $hash{$_} = '';
}
```

I wonder if it is possible to realize this with 1 split command

```
my %Hash = split (/\s/, $line);
```

nope, this code didn't work... any suggestion?

Comment: In almost all practical cases, this is a redundant operation. If you tell me why you think you need this, I can show you an alternative solution.

Comment: i think it would work faster than my code because the $line contains too long text, so @tmp may contain more than 1000 items

Comment: Why does `$line` being a long string make things slower?

Comment: iterating over 1000 items would take some time right? so a single split line may work a bit faster

Comment: Well, `for (0 .. 1_000_000) { }` does not even take a second on my computer. So it depends on what you do when you iterate.

Comment: yeah its just a nanosecond but code is not that short and its a little part of it, optimizing this and the whole code will give me some seconds

Comment: I'm trying to get you to say what it is that you intend to do with this hash, and why you think initializing it this way will help speed your program up.

Comment: TLP: the objective is to create a fast way to decide whether arbitrary words occur in the input ... this is a common operation, I use it in several scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my @tmp = split(/\s/, $line);

my %hash;
@hash{@tmp} = ("") x @tmp;
```

or

```
my %hash = map { $_ => "" } split(/\s/, $line);
```